# Inference variable T has incompatible bounds lower bounds: Integer

Tags: java, arrays, generics, comparable

I got the following code:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void isPalindrome(T[] array)
{
    //body

}
```

and also these arrays:

```
Integer[] intArray = {1,2,5,7,9,0,7};          
Integer[] intArray2 = {1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1};         
String[]  strArray = {"a","b","c","c","b","a"};   
String[]  strArray2 = {"a","b","c","e","f","a"};  


isPalindrome(intArray);
isPalindrome(intArray2);
isPalindrome(strArray);  
isPalindrome(strArray2);
```

before I compile and when I hover over ispalindrome it shows me the following error:

```
  method isPalindrome in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T[]
  found: String[]
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    upper bounds: Comparable<T>
    lower bounds: String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>isPalindrome(T[])
```

I tried to use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` but it didn't work.

Edit:

I tried but nothing works for me

I have also `Comparable.java` class

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    
    
    int compareTo(T other);
}
```

Comment: [Works fine here](https://ideone.com/VLM0Er).

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Try a clean rebuild.

Comment: The code seems good and It works fine.

Comment: Show the _fully-qualified_ name of `Comparable` in your `isPalindrome` signature.

Comment: Why do you compare with `compareTo()` instead of `equals()`?